# Correct code for linear mixed model analysis in R - What is the best way to visualise model data with raw data?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, data-visualization

I am hoping to see if there is an association between a biomarker (NLR) and lung function (FEV1), and have repeated measurements from the same individuals. I performed a linear mixed model analysis in R.

My code is as follows:

```r
library(ggeffects)
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)
library(effects)
require(devtools)
library(MuMIn)

model <- read.csv(file.choose())

#Linear mixed model
NLR.lmm <- lmer(FEV1~ Log.NLR + (1+ Log.NLR|Patient), data = model)
summary(NLR.lmm)
confint(NLR.lmm)
sjPlot:: tab_model(NLR.lmm)

#Calculate R2
r.squaredGLMM(NLR.lmm)
```

[image: Link to my scatter plot]

I ended up with an R2 of 0.74. However, when I plot the model with raw data, the points do not seem to demonstrate an association at all. Was any of my code wrong and are there any better ways to visualise the model in a plot?

Comment: Hi! I am an NLR fan for Heart Failure haha. nice to see someone else interested in NLR..

Consider running it with ggpubr see if you get the same result for the R2
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/78-perfect-scatter-plots-with-correlation-and-marginal-histograms/

Comment: You're plotting the overall (i.e., population level) regression model.  Since you have random intercepts and slopes, you've really got a different line for each patient, so you could plot those out, too.